# Error trying to load mySQL data to Hadoop

Tags: python, mysql, pyspark, pycharm

So this code can now read data from MySQL and is completely connected. I am now receiving errors when it comes to load the data into Hadoop.
I did a small test and saved the file to home/Download before I load it in to Hadoop, and it worked. But now when I give the hdfs directory I get all these errors.

```
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder\
    .appName("SqoopReplacement")\
    .master("local[*]")\
    .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "/home/amel/Downloads/mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar")\
    .getOrCreate()

jdbcDF = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDb") \
    .option("dbtable", "myTable") \
    .option("user", "Amel") \
    .option("password", "Amel@-1998") \
    .load()

print(jdbcDF.show())

jdbcDF.write.parquet("/usr/local/hadoop/text.sql")
```

**KEEP IN MIND:**

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64

export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin/java

$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version openjdk version "1.8.0_292"

java -version openjdk version "1.8.0_292"

python --version Python 3.7.3

spark-submit --version 2.4.2
```

**These are the errors I'm getting**

```
  21/08/07 14:34:39 ERROR FileOutputCommitter: Mkdirs failed to create file:/usr/local/hadoop/text.sql/_temporary/0
21/08/07 14:34:40 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create file:/usr/local/hadoop/text.sql/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_202108071434395647081834630803094_0001_m_000000_1 (exists=false, cwd=file:/home/amel/PycharmProjects/connect-to-mysql)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:458)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:443)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1118)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1098)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.HadoopOutputFile.create(HadoopOutputFile.java:74)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.<init>(ParquetFileWriter.java:248)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:390)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:349)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.<init>(ParquetOutputWriter.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(ParquetFileFormat.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.newOutputWriter(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.<init>(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:269)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$15(FileFormatWriter.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Comment: your URL is wrong. If you add the protocol `hdfs` at the begining, you should also add the ip address of the serveur : `"hdfs://<ip>/user/Amel"`. Otherwise, simply write : `/user/Amel` without `hdfs` in front.

Comment: Hey Steven, I just updated my question. It seems I'm getting new sets of errors

Comment: What is it that you don't understand in the error message ? `Mkdirs failed to create file:/usr/local/hadoop/text.sql/_temporary/0`?

Comment: I used the wrong port. It work now. Thanks for helping me Steven.

Answer (score 0):

The error was i used the wrong port

```
jdbcDF.write.parquet("hdfs://localhost:54310/user/amel/test.csv")
```